# Mailchimp form : set default date field to TODAY

Tags: mailchimp

I have defined a form in Mailchimp with a field of type date. I would like the default value for this field to be TODAY. I would prefer this value to be set at the Mailchimp end rather than in the browser of the user or in the Wordpress application used to subscribe to Mailchimp.

Is there a way to set the default value to TODAY in Mailchimp?